# Unresolved function or method collection() - Firestore node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, webstorm, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have this error in my Firestore cloud function. I am using WebStorm and node.js. I have no idea why it doesn't work..

If anyone knows why this is happening I will appreciate some help!

This is my function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.httpTest =  functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

const db = admin.firestore();

const articlesRef = db.collection('articles_common');
const query = articlesRef.where('locked', '==', false).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });

res.send("Http test function");


console.log( "HttpTest - Cron-job.org triggered  ")
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`collection()` is imported from `@google-cloud/firestore` that, being an indirect project dependency, is not indexed. In your project `node_modules` folder, select `@google-cloud` directory, right click, choose **Mark directory as | Not Excluded**. This should solve the issue

[image]